# Metabox Data not being saved

Tags: post-meta, metabox

My meta box won't save data. It's a select form field and when I select and update the post, there's nothing selected on refresh.

So here it is on PasteBin.
http://pastebin.com/tfrgasQC

Can anyone tell why my code won't get wordpress to save the post with the data?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If that is all of your code, you're missing a `save_post` action to save the data. Refer to the code sample provided on [add_meta_box](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box).

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_my_meta_box_data' );

function save_my_meta_box_data( $post_id ){
    // make sure it's not an autosave
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
        return;

    // verify your nonce
    if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['my_noncename'], 'my-nonce' ) )
        return;

    // check post type, permissions
    // validate your $_POST data
    // update_post_meta();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! What is a nonce though? I looked it up and it's security related. I don't have any nonces that I know of.

Comment: Oh I see, your code wasn't meant to be pasted into my file. LOL sorry... I don't know anything about coding :/

Comment: Can you show me how to write the save function for my specific code? I'm sorry for asking but I've been working on this all day, trying to write save functions different ways since I don't know php, and it just fails every time.

Comment: ok I figured it all out using something else... don't know how to show it here though... wish I could delete this question. waste of space, sorry guys